# Left Join with Null Script Efficiency Explanation Needed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Why would I use a `LEFT JOIN` in SQL in a `FROM` clause and attach a `WHERE` clause where the entity "is null"? I was told this is a very efficient script and I should learn the methodology behind it.

For example:

```
FROM
    something
    LEFT JOIN aRow a AND bRow b AND cRow c AND dRow d
WHERE
    bRow.b IS NULL;
```

Comment: Because that is an efficient way to accomplish what you want to do, according to at least one source.

Comment: Is this a MySQL thing or a Microsoft SQL Server thing? Each database has different capabilities.

Comment: no big difference if you put `bRow.b is null` after `join`, but hard to understand

Comment: Think about it. You have one table "something" that will pull all the data and now you are "left joining" on another table. But that 2nd table has rows of rows of data. Some are nulls and some are not. You now put a restriction on the where clause to say "I want only to return rows that are NULLS vs all rows"

Comment: You should also stop using that outdated join syntax... https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You need to pick the correct RDBMS, please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: is this valid join syntax ? can you do left join table and table and table ?

Comment: RDBMS is irrelevant in this case. This is ultimately a fairly generic SQL language question.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of construct is used when you specifically want to know something like "a list of all customers who have never ordered anything" :

```
SELECT
  customer.*
FROM
  customers
  LEFT JOIN 
  orders
  ON
    orders.customerid = customers.id
WHERE
  orders.id IS NULL
```

Or to quote an old manager of mine: "Can you get the database to give me a list of everything that isn't in the database?"

Me> "Sure, can you give me a list of what things the database should tell you it doesn't have?"

Him> "How am I supposed to know that?"

Comment: Guido: please don't edit my SQL to make it more ugly. Your opinion on the appearance of my SQL is your own. If you want a list of justifications as to why I lay my SQL out like this then let's chat about it, but don't presume that it's acceptable to edit my posts for such trivialities without discussing it first; it's rude!

Comment: you call this not ugly ? OK than hahaha

Comment: @GuidoG It's not as much about aesthetics (the "beauty reference") as much as not forcing your views on people. It is, indeed, rude, and implying that your tastes are better is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

This really is a fairly generic, non-RDBMS-specific question. The logic will apply to pretty much any flavor of SQL. And this is a technique that anyone who works with data queries should be familiar with.

For all intents and purposes (and moving past the flawed syntax in the OP),  this is the same query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.col1 NOT IN ( 
    SELECT table2.col1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.col2 = <filterHere> 
)
```

When you are dealing with a couple of hundred rows, you may not see a significant difference in performance. But when you're working with just a few million rows in both tables, you will most definitely see a significant performance increase in

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
    AND table2.col2 = 42
WHERE table2.id IS NULL
```

---

Let's illustrate what is happening with these queries.

Create test tables.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 int, col2 varchar(10)) ;
INSERT INTO table1 ( col1, col2 )
VALUES (1,'a')
, (2,'b')
, (3,'c')
, (4,'d')

CREATE TABLE table2 (col1 int, col2 varchar(10)) ;
INSERT INTO table2 ( col1, col2 )
VALUES (1,'a')
, (3,'c')
```

This gives us

```
table1
col1 col2
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d

table2
col1 col2
1    a
3    c
```

Now we want the columns that are in `table1` but not in `table2`.

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.col1 NOT IN ( 
    SELECT t2.col1 FROM table2 t2 
)
```

We can't `SELECT` anything from `table2`, because that table is just a sub-query and not part of the whole query. It's not available to us.

This breaks down to

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.col1 NOT IN ( 1,3 )
```

Which further breaks down to

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.col1 <> 1
    OR t1.col1 <> 3
```

These queries give us

```
col1 col2
2    b
4    d
```

That's a subquery broken down into 2 different `OR` statements to filter our results.

So lets look at a `JOIN`. We want all of the records on the left side, and only include those on the right side that match. So

```
SELECT t1.col1 AS t1_col1, t1.col2 AS t1_col2, t2.col1 AS t2_col1, t2.col2 AS t2_col2 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

With a `JOIN`, both tables are available to our `SELECT`, so we can see which records in `tablel2` match up to those in `table1`. The above gives us

```
t1_col1  t1_col2  t2_col1  t2_col2
1        a        1        a
2        b        NULL     NULL
3        c        3        c
4        d        NULL     NULL
```

With the extra data, we can see that col1 for 2 and 4 don't match in the two tables. We can now filter those out with a simple `WHERE` statement.

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL
```

Giving us

```
col1 col2
2    b
4    d
```

There's no subquery and just one statement in the filter. Plus, this allows the engine's optimizer to make a more efficient query plan.

It's impossible to see a difference in performance when we're only dealing with a couple of rows, but multiply these tables by a few million rows, and you will definitely see how much faster a `JOIN` can be.